Why wouldn't one use a DAC for an RF transmitter?
I'm wondering what would be the reasons that someone would use something other than a DAC to generate IF signals before they're mixed up to RF. With how fast modern DACs can be (30 MSPS from some quick research), it seems to me that there isn't any situation where doing a hardware implementation of BPSK or whatever would be better than just using a DAC. Is this correct?

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation#Digital_QAM

Are you thinking that this isn't done?  It certainly is.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesis

A basic Direct Digital Synthesizer consists of a frequency reference (often a crystal or SAW oscillator), a numerically controlled oscillator (NCO) and a digital-to-analog converter (DAC)

Or are you asking what are the cons of DDS?  Basically just that you need higher performance digital processing, which affects price, size, power consumption, etc.  Note that economy of scale may outweigh the need for higher specs, and reduction in analog filtering circuitry typically does outweigh the size and power consumption of increased digital processing.

Isn't he asking the opposite - what would be the reasons /not to/ use a high speed DAC? That's at least how I interpret the question. Edit you touch upon it of course

Yes, I was asking about the cons of DDS, which you touched on a little in your response.
